# Proof that $2^{10}+5^{12}$ is a composite number

Tags: proof-explanation

A hint or full answer will help a lot, because I have no idea what to do.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+2%5E10%2B5%5E12

Comment: It is a number of the form $a^4+4b^4$ and $$ a^4+4b^4 = (a^2-2ab+2b^2)(a^2+2ab+2b^2)$$

Comment: this has found Sophie Germain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$5^{12}+4\cdot 2^{8} = (5^6-2\cdot 5^3 \cdot 2^2+2\cdot 2^4)(5^6+2\cdot 5^3 \cdot 2^2+2\cdot 2^4)$$

Using $a^4+4b^4 =(a^2-2ab+2b^2)(a^2+2ab+2b^2)$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: This can be expressed as the difference of two squares in a reasonably easy way.

Comment: Note that factorising by using the difference of two squares is a respectable technique.